# Java 8: groupingBy with associated object's property? [Cyclic Inference]

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8

This is how my `Test` looks like:

```
@Test
    public void testFunctional() 
    {
        final Member member = new Member("email", "memberExternalId", "clientId", "clientSecret");
        final Category foodCategory = new Category("Groceries", "Food");
        final Category utilityCategory = new Category("Internet", "utility");

        final List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
        {
            transactions.add(new Transaction("food1", new BigDecimal("10.00"), true, LocalDateTime.now(), member, foodCategory));
            transactions.add(new Transaction("food2", new BigDecimal("20.00"), true, LocalDateTime.now(), member, foodCategory));
        }
        {
            transactions.add(new Transaction("utility1", new BigDecimal("100.00"), true, LocalDateTime.now(), member, utilityCategory));
            transactions.add(new Transaction("utility2", new BigDecimal("200.00"), true, LocalDateTime.now(), member, utilityCategory));
        }

        final Map<String, List<BigDecimal>> groupByCategory = transactions.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Category::getGroupName));
    }
```

`Category` looks like this:

```
public class Category 
{
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "group_name", nullable = false)
    private String groupName;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
...
}
```

When I do:

```
final Map<String, List<BigDecimal>> groupByCategory = transactions.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Category::getGroupName));
```

IntelliJ complains with `Cyclic Inference`

I am trying this `Java 8` feature for the first time and not sure what's causing this.

[image]

Comment: Your `transactions` list contains `Transaction` values. Where do you expect the `Category::getGroupName` to be applied?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but every `Transaction` has `Category` which has `groupName`, I want to group transactions based on their `groupName`. Does that makes sense?

Comment: So you want `Transaction`s to be grouped by the name of their `Category`?

Comment: grouped by `groupName` of the `Category`. If you see in code above `Category` has `groupName`

Comment: The IDE might be reporting a misleading error message. The first thing you need to ask yourself is: "How does Java use `Category::getGroupName` given a value of type `Transaction` (provided by the `stream()`)?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your input is a `List<Transaction>`, from which you create a `Stream<Transaction>`.
When you collect this `Stream` into a `Map`, you should supply a Collector that would map each `Transaction` to the key under which is should be grouped.

You want to group the `Transaction`s by the `GroupName` of the `Category` of the `Transaction`. Since `Category::getGroupName` is not a method of `Transaction`, you can't use a method reference here. Instead, you can use a lambda expression :

```
final Map<String, List<Transaction>> groupByCategory = 
    transactions.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t.getCategory().getGroupName()));
```

Also note that this grouping would produce a `Map<String, List<Transaction>>`, not `Map<String, List<BigDecimal>>`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out. So in case I wanted to add amount in `Transaction` I should apply `Map-Reduce` on the `Map` created above, right?

Comment: @daydreamer What do you mean by "add amount in Transaction"?

Comment: The `BigDecimal` in my map was for adding all the `amount` in `Transaction` when grouped by `groupName`. Does that makes sense?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get amounts grouped by category then you can combine the `groupingBy` collector with a `mapping` collector:

```
    Map<String, List<BigDecimal>> amountsByCategory = transactions.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t.getCategory().getGroupName(),
                     Collectors.mapping(Transaction::getAmount, 
                     Collectors.toList())));
```

It's also possible to get total amounts per group using `Collectors.reducing`:

```
    Map<String, BigDecimal> totalAmountByCategory = transactions.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t.getCategory().getGroupName(),
                     Collectors.mapping(Transaction::getAmount, 
                     Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add))));
```

Comment: I think it is very useful the first part: it is a common case: in a collection of objects typically you have a property as the key to group by (groupname) and another as the value of interest (amount) to put in a list. Thanks.